# How to convert a series as the new dataframe column name appending the history price for each of the column name?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Firstly, i get the cryptocurrency name through:

```
tickers=pd.DataFrame(tickers)
coin=tickers['symbol'].head(10)
coin
```

Then, I get define a function which can get historical price for each of the coin name from above code:

```
def get_price(name):
    df=CmcScraper(name,"01-01-2019","05-10-2019")
    df=df.get_dataframe().set_index("Date")
    return df
```

So how can i get a dataframe with coin name as the column names and the historical Close prices as the series for each of the coin name. The index for the new dataframe is date?
Appreciate if any answer.

It gave me the IndexError: list index out of range, if i tried the following code:

```
df=pd.concat([get_price(key)["Close"].rename(key) for key in coin],axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([get_price(key)[Close].rename(key) for key in coin],axis=1,join='outer')
```

in this case the index would be **Time**.

---

if the index is not the same for all data frames, an error could be generated. In this case you could use:

```
pd.concat([get_price(key)[Close].rename(key).reset_index() for key in coin],axis=1,join='outer')
```

if you don't mind losing information about the `Date`:

```
pd.concat([get_price(key)[Close].rename(key) for key in coin],ignore_index=True,axis=1,join='outer')
```

Comment: Not sure why, when i type this code, it still gives me the erros of "IndexError: list index out of range"   >>>    df=pd.concat([get_price(key)["Close"].rename(key) for key in coin],axis=1)

Comment: The DataFrames may have different indexes. Or that they don't have the same length. Although that is less likely. Have you tried the other two codes of my answer?

Comment: try ignore_index=True

Comment: Does the error occur in the get_price function or out?

Comment: i tried ignore_index=True . But it gave me the same errors and i reduced the coin to include only 3 coins whose index are the same. But the same errors

Comment: no, i tried get_price function to get history data for bitcoin but it works well

Comment: All the closing columns are called 'Close'?

Comment: yes, i have all of them called "Close",.  I reload and run the code for like 10 times, it works now. But it does not work again when i reload one more time. Not sure why

Comment: where are you saving the result of the expression? Could you modify your answer and copy and paste your code? I need it to solve the problem

Comment: Anyway, for what you explain to me, I don't think it's a code problem